# Is there any Magmi alternate for Magento 2.3.5?

Tags: magento2, import, magmi

Is there any extension available for Magento 2.3.5  like Magmi which can create categories and products from csv file.

Regards.

Comment: https://www.cobby.io/ but it's a paid platform

Comment: Thanks Ricky. I will check it.

Comment: Does it accept same csv file as Magmi do? Can we run process of importing through url in code(script file) instead of hitting vutton etc in admin panel?

Comment: It's an excel plugin, so you edit stuff in excel and click save, it then pushes automatically to Magento. I've not used in a while though

Comment: Hello, is there any other extension available to import categories and products from csv file?